# SQL query to delete duplicate rows from same table?

Tags: sql

suppose there is a employee table containing columns name, id and salary having 2 or more than two rows with same values in all three rows...then how to write a query to delete duplicate rows..

Comment: Is this a homework question? It would help us if you specified which database you are using - as the syntax could differ.

Comment: Curious, what is the primary key of this table?  Since typically most will use "ID" as the primary key.  If "ID" is the primary key.  Then how do you have duplicates? Sounds like a issue with your Primary Key constraint.

Comment: Sounds more like how to find duplicate questions on SO  search: +delete +duplicate

Answer (score 8):

[Here](http://jzinedine.blogspot.com/2010/11/delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server.html) is a nice way if you use Sql Server

```
with duplicates as
(select * ,ROW_NUMBER() over(

      partition by id,name, salary
      order by id,name, salary) rownum
from Person)
delete from duplicates where rownum > 1
```

Comment: +1 the comment is for me to increase the chance to find the link again, when I need it.

Answer (score 3):

assuming ID is the primary key:

```
delete P
from Person P right outer join
(
   select name, min(id) as id
   from Person
   group by name
) unique_people
on P.id = unique_people.id
where P.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

u can set unique key to to your field ...
otherwise you can delete all the duplicate row
by

delete from **table_name** where id=@id and name=@name

Answer (score 0):

Insert the distinct rows from the original table to new temporary table. 
Delete data from original duplicate table then insert the distinct rows from the temporary table to original table.

```
select distinct * into temp From Emp;
delete from Emp;
insert into Emp(name,ID,salary) as select * from temp; 
drop table temp;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM tablename WHERE columemane='name'
```

Supposing I have 2 duplicate rows in table **student**:

name   |  number |  last name

Manoj | 1125256  | Sharma

Manoj | 1125256  | Sharma

I want to delete one using the following query

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM student WHERE name='Manoj'
```

Comment: This works only when you have two rows, not if you have more duplicate records.