# MS SQL - find and delete duplicities

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)
>   [SQL query to delete duplicate rows from same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510596/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-same-table)

How to find duplicity for example in this table?

[image]

Column **A** is unique ID and columns **E** and **F** are irrelevant, so **rows 1,2,3** and rows **4,5** are duplicates

Comment: You may have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows/3822833#3822833) and many others.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510596/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-same-table/4510642#4510642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a more effective solution:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable 
    WHERE A NOT IN 
        (SELECT MIN(A) 
         FROM MyTable GROUP BY B, C, D
        );
```

Attention: this works if "A" is not NULL. So, for some similar tasks it won't help.

Comment: Yep, it's really nice solution! Thank you too, Gangnus

Answer (score 1):

```
select MyTable.A 
from MyTable 
     join (select B,C,D 
           from MyTable 
           group by B,C,D 
           having Count(*)>1) as T2 on MyTable.B = T2.B 
                                       and MyTable.C = T2.C 
                                       and MyTable.D = T2.D
```

Comment: This query deletes all records, but suppose to delete duplication, so if some values is in two rows then it should delete on row, not all rows, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Md. Elias Hossain - This is a select not a delete. Be carefull if you want delete the duplication and hold one row of the duplicated rows. Which one must stay in the table? I prefare to see the selection and then delete the rows manual

Comment: Thats fine, but the asker was looking for `DELETE` statement and I'm sure he'll not be able to find which row he should keep among duplicate rows, however the asker accepted your answer, thats okay according to him, thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, i've updated it by `select B, C, D, MIN(X) as id` and `on ... and MyTable.id <> T2.id` and it works perfectly. Thank you :) (completly the same result as answer of Gangnus bellow)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**`select count(A) Occurrence, B, C, D from TableName group by B, C, D having count(A) > 1`**

To get the IDs of the duplicated Columns use:

**`select A from TableName where (B + ' ' + C + ' ' + D) in
(select B + ' ' + C + ' ' + D from TableName group by B, C, D having count(A) > 1)`**

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below query:

```
WITH CustomTable
 AS (SELECT  B, C, D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B, C, D 
                                   ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RowNumber
     FROM   TableName)
DELETE FROM CustomTable
WHERE  RowNumber > 1
```